# "\N" within a case when statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the best way to use a case when statement that employs a "\N" ?  I have a column of State data in which a "\N" populates when no state exists (for foreign countries).  I'm trying to write a smile case when statement that changes the \N's to "unknown" but am receiving a  Error: Invalid string literal: "\N".  Is there a way to get around this?

SELECT 
STATE_REGION, case when STATE_REGION = "\N" then "unknown" else 'STATE_REGION' end as state_region_two
FROM xxx

Comment: You can try `'\\N'`, but more likely `'/N'`.  Note the forward slash.

Comment: In Title and Body of your question - you use two versions '\N' and '/N' - please clarify what exactly you have in your data

Comment: Apologies for that.  The no states are appearing as "\N".  Just fixed that.

Comment: Just tried SELECT 
STATE_REGION, case when STATE_REGION = "\\N" then "unknown" else 'STATE_REGION' end as state_region_two     And it solved the issue.  Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STATE_REGION, 
  CASE 
    WHEN STATE_REGION = "\\N" THEN "unknown" 
    ELSE 'STATE_REGION' 
  END AS state_region_two 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

... yet another option is

```
    WHEN STATE_REGION = r"\N" THEN "unknown"
```